# Output disappears quickly after adding loop

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dosbox

I need to insert a new element at the beginning of an array. After adding the code below to the rest of my code the output changes and then quickly disappears.  Once I remove this code everything goes back to normal. Is there something wrong with my loop? I've just started using loops and I'd appreciate your help.

```
                            ;fix array positions
mov cx,hlength-1            ;i.e array of length 5 loop 4 times (don't need old tail)
fixarr:
mov si,cx
mov ax,h[si-1]
mov h[si],ax                ;i.e length = 5 s[4]=s[3]
loop fixarr    
mov ax,hhead  

mov h[0],ax
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing but if your array is byte sized, you should use a byte sized register, e.g. `al` not `ax`. If your array is made of words, then you need to scale by 2.

Comment: My array is made of words, So you're saying I should add dec cx after fix arr ? @jester

Comment: You should `add si, si` to scale by 2, and also use `mov ax, h[si - 2]`.

Comment: `fixarr:
mov si,cx
add si,si
mov ax,h[si-2]
mov h[si],ax   ;i.e length = 5 s[4]=s[3]
loop fixarr    
mov ax,hhead           
mov h[0],ax`   Here's what I did but the program  seems to have gone into an infinite loop this time . I must've understood you wrong @jester

Comment: That's what I meant, and that can't cause it to go into infinite loop since `loop` is controlled by `cx` and that's never infinite. The problem must be elsewhere in code not shown.

Comment: I don't know the code seems to work fine when I remove this loop.That's really strange@jester

Comment: Maybe the rest of the code depends on the value of `cx`, `si` or `ax` and those are of course destroyed. Maybe `hlength` is incorrect so this overwrites some out of range memory.

Comment: I return from the procedure right after this loop so I don't need cx,si,ax. It could be `hlength`. There's something else I'm using this loop under a label. i.e. `label:` code `fixarr:` Would this cause a problem ? @jester

Comment: Is `hlength` the number of bytes or number of elements in the array?

Comment: You decrement `cx` by `1` in each loop, but copy a 16-bit value.

Comment: I don't need the last array element anymore that's why I started with `mov cx,length-1` actually now I think it should be `mov cx,length-2` but still it makes no difference. I don't really want to extend by one element I need to overwrite the last element @WeatherVane

Comment: I deleted that comment, after I saw you discard the last element. But still, your array pointer is moving by one, but copying 2 bytes.

Comment: hlength was first the number of elements sorry I got conused :'D @WeatherVane i think I should leave it `mov cx,length-1`

Comment: That's about as much as we can help without you providing [mcve].

Comment: If `hlength` is the number of 16-bit elements, you'll need a way of doubling that index, as @Jester wrote.

Comment: The problem is my code is really long and I wanted to keep it "minimal" ,I'll try to post a better version ,and I appreciate your help @jester

Comment: If you want to step by two, stop using the `loop` instruction.  It's slow anyway.  Just use `si` as your loop counter, with `sub si, 2 / jge`.  That's *way* easier than copying `cx` and then scaling it, since you're writing 16 bit code so you can't use a scaled addressing mode (like `[h + ecx*2]`).